# Template syntax explanation

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

On some resource I saw a code:

```
struct C
{
    template <typename T, typename = typename enable_if<!is_same<C, typename decay<T>::type>{}>::type>
    C(T&& f){}
}
```

I tried my best but still need some clarification. I know this scary thing is needed for the `SFINAE` idiom - if something fails the templated function simply will not be created. Here what I found:

1. `typename decay<T>::type` - this removes cv qualifiers from type `T`, or converts an array `T` to pointer `T` or converts `T` to function pointer. But what is this `typename` before? I suppose this is related to dependent type, i.e. the supplied type `T` is a thing that is a part of another template, right?
2. `is_same<A, B>{}` - what is this `{}` braces doing here? Why?
3. `typename enable_if<A>::type` - as I understood if `A` is true the `type` field exist and in this case it's `void` since only one argument was passed to `enable_if`, right? But again - what is this `typename` before?
4. `template <typename T, typename = typename A>` - what is this `typename = typename A`? Where's the argument name at all?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, **typename** keyword in that case says to compiler that decay::type is really type (but not static variable of `std::decay<T>`, for example)
2. `std::is_same` has cast operator to bool, and through {} object of that type is created and then converted to bool (at compile time). Alternative variant is `std::is_same<...>::value`
3. If `std::is_same` returns true, then member *type* of `std::enable_if` is exists and SFINAE can pass through that function
4. Parameter name is not needed in that context (because it isn't used somewhere)

P.S. `std::enable_if` looks like that

```
template<bool B, class T = void>  //(1)
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>  /(2)
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

So, if the first parameter is *false* then primary template (1) is selected and it has not *type* member, but in case when it is *true* specialization (2) is selected